# Arquillian Integration test cannot run with maven only run with eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I created some integration tests for testing my facade layer. I run my application on Jboss 7 server.

The integration test run via eclipse IDE but when I tried to run on console with 
**mvn clean install** 
the following exception was shown:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor
```

Everything works fine with IDE. I use junit.

And this is my external dependency section :

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-transaction-jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Alpha3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Could you share your maven dependency section? I believe you are missing the connector definition (managed, remote).